# Using JSF or using Mojarra?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, richfaces, mojarra

I have an important question.

I have worked with JSF 1.2 in the past. I haved use some basic tags like

```xml
<h:outputText />
<h:commandButton />
<h:commandLink />
<h:dataTable />
```

and RichFaces like this

```xml
<rich:calendar />
<rich:togglePanel />
<rich:dataScroller />
```

To use ajax functionality, i worked with

```xml
<a4j:support />
<a4j:jsFunction />
<a4j:queue />
```

for example. I have used q jetty webserver to use the JSF tags. Today i work since one Week with JSF 2.0, PrimeFaces and the glassfish application server.

So i have the following question: Have I worked with JSF or have I worked with Mojarra? Sorry, but the exactly differences between there technologies are not clearly for me.

Thanks a lot !
Maik

Answer (score 8):

JSF is a Java EE standard or specification (just like JPA, EJB, etc).

A standard or specification needs to be implemented. Mojarra is Oracle's implementation of JSF. Myfaces is another JSF implementation, developed by Apache.

So, if you are using Glassfish, you are using Oracle's implentation of JSF: Mojarra.
If for example you use Tomee(Apache's application server), you are going to be using Apache's implementation of JSF: Myfaces.

https://javaserverfaces.java.net/ https://myfaces.apache.org/ https://glassfish.java.net/ https://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html

Comment: thanks for the answer. And what kind of JSF Implementation i use, if i work with a jetty jsp/servelt/webserver container?

Comment: Jetty and Tomcat don't provide any JSF implementation, you would have to take care of bundling a JSF implementation(like Mojarra or Myfaces) with your app or adding it to the webserver libraries.